# Why this code for getting all sub-strings of a string not working (Python)?

Tags: python, object

I am using object-oriented.   When doing separately it gives the right answer but in classes it gives runtime error on ideone.com. Why so? What am I doing wrong here?

```
class abc:
        def _init_(self):
            self.s=""
            subs=[]
        def draw(self):
            self.s=raw_input()
            for i in range(0,len(self.s)+1):
                for j in range(i+1,len(self.s)+1):
                    subs.append(self.s[i:j])
        def printt(self):
            for each in subs:
                print each
k=abc()
k.draw()
k.printt()
```

Comment: It seems the bug is in `subs` when it should be `self.subs`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line of `__init__` (note that `__init__` has two `_` on either side, not just one).

```
def __init__(self):
    self.s = ""
    self.subs = []  # needed self
```

Then in `draw` this line should be

```
self.subs.append(self.s[i:j])
```

Same thing in `printt`

```
def printt(self):
    for each in self.subs:
        print each
```

Comment: Oh God. I didn't see that. Thank you!

Comment: class abc:
 def _init_(self):
  self.s=""
  self.subs=[]
 def draw(self):
  self.s=raw_input()
  for i in range(0,len(self.s)+1):
   for j in range(i+1,len(self.s)+1):
    #print self.s[i:j]
    self.subs.append(self.s[i:j])
 def printt(self):
  for each in self.subs:
   print each,


k=abc()
k.draw()
k.printt()
Its again wrong! Why?

Comment: You still didn't fix `__init__`, you need two `_` on each side